# how can i fix bootstrap carousel dimensions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

this is the carousel i am working on.
[image]

the container for this carousel is 7 bootstrap columns wide.
how can i fix this carousel to fit in the full width of the container irrespective of the image width, the image is image-responsive.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7 slider t">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class ="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1 class="">some heading</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h2>main heading</h2>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="img-responsive">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h2>some heading</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dabbled with this in one of my projects.  What you want is for the `.item` to fill the `.carousel-inner`, and the image in the `.item` to fill the width and ignore the height constraints.  So you force the image to have `100%` width and no `max-height` property and have the container `.item` clip the overflow.  I use about `500px` for the height limit on desktop devices, `400px` for tablets, and `300px` for mobile devices, though you can use any height you want.

```
.carousel-inner {
    height: 500px;
}

.carousel-inner .item {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner .item img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-height: none;
}
```